# Is that possible to create query using findAll() and get filtered result by using ForeignKey from pivot (relation many-to-many)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have two tables `Users` and `Lists` I created an association third table (many-to-many) with Foreign keys Pivot as `Editors`. I want to return `Lists` to `req.user.id` based on pivot `FK_Editors_User_Id` and then get all of the other `editors` in one query. I can do where query using `FK_Editors_User_Id` when query inside includes user model but when I try to do where on `List.findAll()` then I get the error with `there is no column in List.FK_Editors_User_Id`.
Is that possible to create a query on `List.findAll()` and get the filtered list with `all editors` at one moment query?

Get list method which one should return all filtered lists which editor can edit and each list return ALL of current other editors.

```
List.findAll({
  where: {
    'FK_EditorsLists_Users_Id': 2
  },
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'title',
    'createdAt',
    'updatedAt'
  ],
  include: [{
    model: User,
    required: true,
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'lastName',
      'firstName',
      'userName',
      'email'
    ]
  }]
})
```

But I can't use `FK_EditorsLists_Users_Id` in this case because sequalize don't see foreign keys from table `Editors` inside `List` model. How can I add FK keys to List model and may it possible to find by `FK_EditorsLists_Users_Id`

[All results without any "where" filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBuWK.png)

[Scenerio 1: Logged in as Ammie should see only 1 list because she can edit only one list also she can see who can edit the list too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmTX7.png)

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I think: you need to inform sequelize which association to use.  Assuming your association is something like this:

```
List.belongsToMany(User, {as: 'list2User', through: Editors, foreignKey: 'list_id', targetKey: 'id'} );
```

then your association needs to say:

```
List.findAll({
   // ... other stuff ...
    include: [{
    model: User,
    required: true,
    as: 'list2User'   // critical!!
   // ... other stuff ...
   where : {id : 2 }
  }]
})
```

My example above would help for all Lists edited by user 2.  But, to get ALL editors of those lists would require another association, I think.